# MVC reusable components vs MVVM reusable components

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture, loose-coupling

I've been developing applications applications for quiet some time now, using MVC and MVVM architecture. After going deeper into those 2 architectures, i've found out that MVVM's components are more loosely coupled than those of MVC. But after doing some research, some say that MVC's components are also loosely coupled and reusable can someone clarify this issue ??

Comment: Why is `MVVM` component are more loosely coupled than `MVC`?

Comment: yes thats the question :)

Answer (score 0):

MVC is the older and base pattern. MVVM pattern is derived from the MVC pattern. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) says

> "Largely based on the model–view–controller pattern (MVC), MVVM is
>   targeted at UI development platforms which support event-driven
>   programming, such as HTML5, Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF),
>   Silverlight and the ZK framework."

Both are providing loosely coupled and reusable layers.

Similar to MVVM, even in MVC pattern, we can use ViewModels: Please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx.

Thanks.